# What should be the next move for Black?

Tags: opening, analysis, positional-play, philidor-defense

Both sides have had equal points untill now. If the Black knight is moved, then  White can move their knight with discovered check. What should  Black do?

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "11"]  

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 Nf6 4. dxe5 dxe5 5. Nxe5 Nxe4 6. Qe2
```

Comment: What moves hold your knight and also make f3 less powerful?

Comment: The sicilian-defense tag definitely does not apply, since Black's c-pawn is untouched. I removed it.

Comment: In the game I played Bf5, white played f3, then I played Nc5, white played Nc6 and queen will be lost. I resigned here. Oh so  are you suggesting Bc5, and after f3 a check. But still knight is in danger

Comment: what was the opening sequence out of curiosity?

Comment: Hi David, this was the opening sequence:
1. e4 e5 
2. Nf3  d6  
3. d4  Nf6 
4. dxe5  dxe5 
5. Nxe5  Nxe4 
6. Qe2

Comment: How did you get here? If the d-pawns are on the board, it's one of those Petroff countergambits that C. Hertan does so well with: 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 Nxe4 4. Qe2 Qe7 5. Qxe4 d6 and so on.

Comment: I hope you realize that Qe2 was a blunder - 6. Qxd8+ Kxd8 7. Nxf7 would put white a rook up (though the knight is mostly dead).

Comment: @friscodelrosario in my sequnce I went with d6 instead of Nf6, and that's how ended up in this situation. The opening sequence is mentioned in the question

Comment: @AlexanderWoo yes I can see that now. But I was playing black and white managed to do better by taking my queen with discovered check at which point I had resigned. Btw any book suggestions from which I can learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your position; I let the engine play it out and the below was the "best" output I received. This is just an old fashioned slog for the centre. A lot of trading going on.

```
[Event "Analysis Request"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2020.09.09"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Unknown"]
[Black "Unknown"]
[Result "*"]
[SetUp "1"]
[FEN "rnbqkb1r/ppp2ppp/8/4N3/4n3/8/PPP2PPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 0 1"]
[PlyCount "10"]

1. Qe2 Qd5 2. Nd3 Be7 3. f3 Nd6 4. Nf4 Qc6 5. Nd3 O-O *



1. Qe2 Ngf6 2. Nd2 Qd5 3. Nxe4 Nxe4 4. Qb5+ c6 5. Qxd5 cxd5
```

Based of the board;
Blacks castled to safety, the white Queen is in danger of (Re8 ... Bh4+). White feels "under developed" and has less control of the board.

Comment: Black should be up material - he started with three knights!

Comment: I realised i stuffed up the fen; it has since been rectified;

Comment: @shatheesh should be all good now;

Comment: I don't know how you used your engine, but if 4.Nf4 followed by 5.Nd3 is the best it comes with in this position, you might as well dump it and think by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this works, btw, how are you letting the engine play, any specific website ?

Comment: @Evargalo Maybe 5.Nd3 is a typo and the engine actually played 5.Nc3 which makes more sense.

Comment: @shateesh I am just using stockfish 12 and letting the engine play from this position onwards with a depth of 50